# Any framework for android to generate layout from html

Tags: android

I want to use a html file in android for generate a layout from html.... any one knows the any framework available  in for android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're several reasons why you need that and what you can do.

- If you are very familiar with HTML and want to build an Android App, you can use [Android WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html) which can use the Chrome engine internally.
- If you're looking for a way to write portable code and have it deployed to Android and others like iPhone etc., then take a look at the tools you'll find like `mobilehtml5` or `appshed`. With the html5 standard, most of these portability tools are based on this.

Finally. I must say, that I'm not aware of any tool that actually generates xml and java from html.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.